# How can I recover my Twitter account password without my old phone?

Tags: twitter, account-recovery

My phone was lost. I remember my email and my number but I can't receive my notification code because I lost my phone two years ago.

How can I receive my account password?

Answer (score 2):

With a valid email address and knowing your telephone number or user name [it seems recovery is very straightforward](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/forgotten-or-lost-password-reset):

> **How to send yourself a password reset via email**
>
> 1. From the sign in page on either twitter.com, mobile.twitter.com, or
>      the Twitter for iOS or Android app, click `Forgot password?`

[image]

> 2. Enter your email address, phone number, or Twitter username. If you have multiple accounts associated with your phone number, you cannot use your phone number during this step.
> 3. Choose the email address where you want to receive the password reset email.
> 4. Check your email inbox. Twitter will immediately send a message to your account's email address.
> 5. Click the reset link in that email.
> 6. Choose a new password.
>
> Note: The password reset links included in these emails are
>   time-sensitive. If you click the link and it doesn't work, try
>   requesting a new one and use the link as soon as you can.